# Comparison between exponential and factorial results

Tags: exponential-function, factorial

I'm developing an algorithm to compare if the result of $n!$ is bigger than $k^m$, but I have problems with big integers, then I need to know if there's some property that I can use to do this without knowing the results.

Help please. :/

Comment: see Stirling formula.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I can't use this formula because I need to compare the size of the results without knowing the values, for example, I need to know if 10000! is bigger than 2^99 without calculating them, because the size of the results are too big for integers on C++ or any other programming language.

Comment: That particular one is easy: 10000! Is a product of 9999 terms consisting of a 2 and 9998 terms >2, so which one is bigger?

Comment: In a loop, multiply consecutive integers and once the result exceeds k, divide by k. Keep track of how many times you divided. Repeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take natural logs of both
and use Stirling.

$$\ln(k^m)
=m \ln(k)
\text{ and }
\ln(n!)
\approx \frac12 \ln(2 \pi)+(n+\frac12)\ln(n) - n.
$$

Comparing these
should be no problem.